# Ability to avoid loading the same spring file multiple times

Tags: spring

When breaking down a large spring file into smaller config files, we sometimes incorrectly import the same file twice. While it is not a problem most of the times, it becomes a problem when you have namespace handler and autoproxies involved. In many cases there are InstanceAlreadyExistsException's and double proxying. Is there a way that I can force that a file with a name is loaded once and only once. If there is no existing way, could someone point me to a starting place from where I can propose a patch that can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine pointed out that there was something that was proposed in [SPR-1142](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1142) that does exactly this.